# Javascript callback function throws error "Callback is not a function" in firefox

Tags: javascript

```
function CascadeDropDowns(parentClass, childClass, action, callback) {
  var DropDownId = $(parentClass + " option:selected").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "/site/" + action,
    data: { DropDownId: DropDownId },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    error: function () {
      alert("An error occurred.");
    },
    success: function (data) {
      var items = "";
      $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
      });
      $(childClass).html(items);
      $(childClass)[0].selectedIndex = 0;
      callback();
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Populates all child drop downs on load
  var callback = function () {
    CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
  };

  CascadeDropDowns(".DeviceTypeDDL", ".ConfigGroupDDL", "GetGroups", callback);

  // Populates all child drop downs parent change
  $(".DeviceTypeDDL").change(function () {
    var callback = function () {
      CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
    };
    CascadeDropDowns(".DeviceTypeDDL", ".ConfigGroupDDL", "GetGroups", callback);
  });
  $(".ConfigGroupDDL").change(function () {
    CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");
  });
});
```

This runs fine and cascades the dropdowns in the right order, but firefox debugger shows an error and ie throws an alert and asks if Id liek to debug.

Any advice would be great

Comment: `callback is not defined in that scope`. Change `var callback` to `window.callback` and see if it works.

Comment: @Jashwant Has nothing to do with scope.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It is because you are not always passing the callback into that method.

```
success: function (data) {
  var items = "";
  $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text + "</option>";
  });
  $(childClass).html(items);
  $(childClass)[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  if(callback) callback();  //check before calling it. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have realised that!

Comment: I feel like "function parameter missing" would be nicer, but I know I'm picky-ish :)

Answer (score 37):

It's because you are not always providing a `callback` to the `CascadeDropDowns` function.

E.g.

`CascadeDropDowns(".ConfigGroupDDL", ".ConfigNameDDL", "GetParameters");`

You should modify your function to treat the `callback` argument as an optionnal argument:

```
if (callback) {
    callback();
}
```

A common shorthand for that is:

```
callback && callback();
```